# Is it possible to access the DataContext of the current page of the frame? How?

Tags: c#, wpf, frame, datacontext

In wpf, is it possible to access the DataContext of the current page of the frame? If YES, how?

If NO, what should I use as replacement for frame so that I can access its DataContext?

If something is not clear, please tell me.

**Update:** For Clarification

I have a `Frame` in `MainWindow.xaml`. I want to access the `DataContext` of the current page displayed in the `Frame`. Let's just say I want to display a `string` property named *title* of the `ViewModel` of the current page. (Let's assume that each page' `ViewModel` has *title* property)

**Update:** Here is my MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Libertalia.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        .
        .
        .
        DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
        >
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <Grid>
                <Frame Panel.ZIndex="1" x:Name="MainFrame" JournalOwnership="OwnsJournal" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" Source="View/BlankPage.xaml" />
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
</Window>
```

Code of the page (just one of it, just a sample):

```
<Page x:Class="Libertalia.View.LoginView"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
      xmlns:behaviors="clr-namespace:Libertalia.Behavior"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      .
      .
      .
      DataContext="{Binding Page1, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
    <DockPanel Margin="200" >

    </DockPanel>
</Page>
```

**UPDATE:** Model, View and ViewModel Relationship

- `MainWindow.xaml` (View) is binded to `MainViewModel.cs` (ViewModel). In short, `MainWindow.xaml's` `DataContext` is `MainViewModel.cs`
- `MainWindow.xaml` (View) has `Frame`
- `Frame` has `Page` (View). `Frame` has many Pages, displayed one at a time.
- `Page` has its own ViewModel (`DataContext`)

What I want to do:

- Access current page' (of the Frame) `DataContext` from the `DataContext` of the MainWindow (MainViewModel).

Comment: Do you mean the access of DataContext of a View from View's code?

Comment: No, I want to access the `DataContext` of the page from `MainWindow.xaml`(the parent of the `Frame`).

Comment: What do you mean by 'the page'?

Comment: If I understand your idea, yes - it is possible in general, but you need to give more details of your view models and views.
Add code and explanaition.

Comment: I ment the real code, because I need to see the relationship between your views and view models.What is a Frame?
Do you mean the View that is the content of your Window?

Comment: The source code is too long because I am doing a shared project and there is so many irrelevant code. Let's see first if I can explain it well enough: The Frame I am talking about is this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.frame(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I have an idea!
I'll try it and post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that it will work for you, because I still don't understand the relationship between view models and models in your architecure, but try to use this idea:

1). My Window1's xaml has following content :

```
<Grid>       
    <Frame Panel.ZIndex="1"
           x:Name="MainFrame"
           JournalOwnership="OwnsJournal"
           NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"
           Source="UserControl1.xaml" />
</Grid>
```

2) UserControl1 has definition of DataContext:

```
 public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MainViewModel();
    }
```

3). The code where I extract and modfy the DataContext of the Content of my Frame:

```
   Window1 window = new Window1();
        //window.Content = uc;


        var aa = window.Content as Grid;

        foreach (var e in aa.Children)
        {
            if (e is Frame)
            {
                Frame f = e as Frame;
                f.ContentRendered += F_ContentRendered;
            }
        }

//only inside of handler of ContentRendered event you can access to the content of your Frame:
  private void F_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var frame = sender as Frame;
        UserControl1 uc1 = frame.Content as UserControl1;
        MainViewModel mvm = uc1.DataContext as MainViewModel;

    }
```

It should work.

Comment: Thank you for the effort. I have added some code to my question for you to better understand my scenario. But as you can see, I am using MVVMLight so many code in separate files, therefore it is hard to post all my code.

Comment: So in your case the BlankPage.xaml have the target DataContext with view model you want to change. Right?

Comment: I tried the main idea I posted in my solution and it still works!
I can access to the DataContext and I can change its properties.
I will change my post a little bit.

Comment: I'm sorry but it is not working for me. Where did you put your third code? I have put it in MainViewModel, am I  right?

Comment: I have figure it out because of your sample. Thanks.