# How to use dynamic DataType in c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, frame, datacontext

Honestly, I don't know how to ask this one. Let me explain my scenario first.

From the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39890450/is-it-possible-to-access-the-datacontext-of-the-current-page-of-the-frame-how/39891656?noredirect=1#comment67075016_39891656) that I have got from my last question:

```
...
var frame = sender as Frame;
UserControl1 uc1 = frame.Content as UserControl1;
MainViewModel mvm = uc1.DataContext as MainViewModel;
...
```

As you can see `frame.Content` changes and it can have different DataType. Therefore, I can't just write `UserControl1`. Now, what can I write as replacement for `UserControl1` ?

**Update:** Added details

- `frame.Content` is changing upon user interaction
- I want to determine the current DataType of the `DataContext` of `frame.Content` during runtime

As always, please tell me if you want clarification.

Comment: You can't have compile-time safety if you don't know what the _actual_ type (or a subtype) is at compile-time.  If you have a small number of possible types that it _could_ be, the cleanest pattern is to check the type and cast as appropriate.

Comment: @DStanley Yes, as off now, I have a small number of possible types that it could be but it is an ongoing project so the number of possible types will increase as we finish the whole project.  Do I really need to manually check its type?  It will be a long series of if statements then.

Comment: @DStanley Another question, how about if all of the `DataContext` has a field named _title_ and it is the only thing that I want to access, is it possible to avoid a long series of if statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the only thing you need out of `frame.Content` is a `DataContext` you may try casting it to `FrameworkElement`, e.g.:

```
var frame = sender as Frame;
FrameworkElement content = frame.Content as FrameworkElement;
MainViewModel mvm = content.DataContext as MainViewModel;
```

If `frame.Content` is not always a `FrameworkElement` you may want to check that first:

```
var frame = sender as Frame;
FrameworkElement content = frame.Content as FrameworkElement;
if (content != null) {
    MainViewModel mvm = content.DataContext as MainViewModel;
    // work with mvm...
}
else {
    // Frame's content is something unexpected.
}
```

Comment: Sorry for late response. Yes, what I need out of `frame.Content` is its `DataContext` but `frame.Content` is changing and is having its own `DataContext`. What can I write as replacement of `MainViewModel` in your example? I also want to determine the DataType (or ObjectType) of the current DataContext at runtime.

Comment: Use `obj.GetType()` method to determine the type of a runtime object and a C# operator `is` to check whether an object is of particular type. If you need to just find out the main window and get its `DataContext`, use `Application.Current.MainWindow` and/or `LogicalTreeHelper.FindLogicalNode` to find an object that has the needed view model.